# Find items in array where item._id is empty

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB document containing an array where each element is supposed to have a non-empty _id. How do I identify array elements where the _id exists but is empty? I have some records like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("123456789012345678912345"),
    "questions" : [
        {
            "_id" : {

            },
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

The question itself has an empty _id. I've tried the following queries, which all return no results:

```
 db.topics.find({ 'questions.$._id': {} })
 db.topics.find({ 'questions.$._id': '' })
```

Comment: Do you have known fields in the other documents?  Could you so for a not exists query on everything?

Comment: Hmm, maybe, The _id either looks like "_id" : ObjectId("123456789012345678912345") or _id: {}

Comment: I think the answers below are better than what I was planning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the positional `$` operator.

```js
db.topics.find({ "questions._id": {} })
```

Comment: Thanks, the $ operator was the thing. Just need the documents with an empty attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to check for the presence of the value of the `_id` field in `questions`, so you could use the `$in` operator like so:

```
db.topics.find({"questions._id": { $in: [null, {}, ""] }})
```

That will find any record where `_id` is either `null`, empty object `{}` or empty string `""`.